# Using a custom exception class

Tags: c#

I created this custom exception class. I want to be able 
to assign errors to moreErrors. 
when I instantiate SampleException and assign errors to moreErrors, it is always null

What am I doing wrong here?

```
        public class SampleException : Exception
        {
            public SampleException(string message):base(message)
            {
            }

            public IEnumerable<string> moreErrors { get; set; }
        }
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code where you instantiate SampleException and set moreErrors.

Comment: Two things are wrong here. 1 - You never assing `moreErrors`, so it'll be always null, use the constructor or an initializer for this. 2 - The type `IEnumerable<string>` is inherently read-only, so you won't be able to add anything to it, use at least `ICollection<string>` instead.

Comment: Why are you doing this instead of using the built in AggregateException? Are you sure an exception is even an appropriate thing to do here? Exceptions should be used for exceptional circumstances. This looks more like something you might use as part of validation logic, which is not an exceptional circumstance.

Comment: That's correct. working on some validations

Comment: The need to write your own exception class is quite rare - Most of the time people write their own exception class it's an indication of a faulty design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use it like below:

```
public class SampleException : Exception
{
    public SampleException(string message, List<string> errorList = null) : base(message)
    {
        ErrorList = errorList;
    }

    public List<string> ErrorList { get; set; }
}
```

and throw exceptions like this:

```
throw new SampleException("Error Message", new List<string>() { "Error 1", "Error 2" });
```